# Unity - Unwanted repeated texture on sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a "2D map" with generated sprites from generated textures made from imported images.
In my example, my "2D map" is 1536*1536 made from 36 sprites (6*6), each one are 256*256.
The whole thing is generated programmatically.

My problem is that each sprite texture seems to be a little smaller than 256px (~255px) so the texture is repeated (the right of the image is repeated at the left - same thing vertically too).

[Bug in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLIAI.png)

As I found [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/599038/black-lines-between-tile-sprites.html?_ga=2.25000761.2090455427.1612693180-46885437.1612197093) (and many other times), I tried to fix it applying a material with pixel snap enabled. It did not work.

I tried to set pixel per unit to 1 too, but did not manage to display properly my sprites (100 time bigger so... with this repeated 100 time bigger line too!).

I tried playing with images settings too (sprite mode, filter mode, pixel per unit...), ... but same thing.

[Image settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7I4V.png)

Any help would be precious on this!

Thanks,

Julien

Comment: and the texture is set to warp mode clamp? this way it should only draw the last pixel from the x and y coordinate. is there an offset applied to the material that creates the red/blue lines?

Comment: BINGO!!! That's it!! Thank nka_Zz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nka_Zz [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240157/unity-unwanted-repeated-texture-on-sprites#comment117110402_66240157), setting texture wrap mode to clamp works like a charm!!!